# How to capture this pattern with regex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to capture the following pattern using `JavaScript` regular expressions?

I would like to capture the first sequence of characters ending at a word boundary. The sequence length should be *minimal* and greater than `N`.

For example.

```
N = 6, input = "aa bb cc ddd ee"
result = "aa bb cc" // the 1st minimal sequence ending at a word boundary > 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work

```
"^.{" + (n+1) + ",}?\b"
```

Answer (score 2):

If I well understood try something like

```
var n   = 6, 
    str = "aa bb cc ddd ee",
    re  = new RegExp("^.{"+ (n+1) +"}.*?\\b");

str.match(re);  // "aa bb cc"
```