# How to match a minimal pattern ending at the end of input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243168/how-to-capture-this-pattern-with-regex-in-javascript)

I would like to find a *minimal* sequence of characters of length > `N`, which starts at a word boundary and ends at the end of input.

For example:

```
N = 5, input = "aaa bbb cccc dd"
result = "cccc dd"
```

I tried `\b.{5,}?$` but it matches the whole `input` rather the *minimal* part.

What `regex` would you suggest?

Comment: Is regex really needed, this is fairly trivial with a simple loop.

Comment: @Shaded I would prefer a regex since it is more "declarative" (as opposed to loops) approach. Besides, I would like to learn "regex" since it looks like a useful tool.

Comment: @Michael, It's definitely a good tool to have, but just be mindful that regex can very often make things more complicated than they have to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem this time isn't greediness, it's eagerness.  Regexes naturally try to find the earliest possible match, and getting them to find the *last* one can be tricky.  The easiest way is usually the one @Arcadien demonstrated: use `.*` to gobble up the whole string, then use backtracking to find the match on the rebound.

I have some questions about your requirements, though.  `\b` can match the beginning or the end of a word, so if (for example) `N=5` and the string ends with `"foo1 bar2"`, the result would be `" bar2"` (notice the leading space).  Do you really want a match that starts at the *end* of a word, or should it drop the space or back up to the beginning of `"foo1"`?  Also, will all words consist entirely of word characters?  If there are any non-word characters, `\b` will be able to match in even more surprising places.

For the regex below, I redefined "word" to mean any complete chunk of non-whitespace characters.  The `.*` starts out by consuming the whole string, then the lookahead - `(?=.{5,})` - forces it to backtrack five positions before it tries to match anything.  The `\s` forces the match to start at the beginning of a word, so the rest of the regex captures one or more complete words.

```
/^.*(?=.{5,})\s(\S+(?:\s+\S+)*$)/

var N = 5;
var regex = "^.*(?=.{" + N + ",})\\s(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)*$)";
var match = regex.exec(subject);
var result = (match != null) ? match[1] : "";
```

This regex won't match anything that's less than five characters long or doesn't contain whitespace.  If that's a problem, let me know and I'll tweak it.

Comment: Great answer ! As for your questions: the result should start at the _beginning_ of the word. A "word" is just a chunk of non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 3):

you just forgot parenthesis around match. Use

```
.*(\b.{5,}?)$
```

Comment: Good solution, though the explanation is poor. The greedy match in front will try to consume as much as possible, so that the text captured will have minimal length while satisfying condition about word boundary.

Comment: So you regex was valid, and it suceeded for "match" operation. To let it return some string part, you need to enclose matching pattern into parenthesis. Then all the text matched by parenthesed pattern will be returned.

Comment: I tried it in `node.js`and got an array of matches: `> "aaaa bbb cccc dd".match(/.*(\b.{5,}?)$/)
[ 'aaaa bbb cccc dd',
  'cccc dd',
  index: 0,
  input: 'aaaa bbb cccc dd' ]
>` Why is "my" match a last one ?

Comment: Just FYI, that `?` isn't doing anything useful.  That part of the regex is already doing a minimal match, just not in the usual way. Anyway, it never makes sense to have a reluctant quantifier as the last thing in the regex, with or without the `$` anchor.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the input by

```
.split("").reverse().join("")
```

And apply the answer from the previous question, then reverse the match with the same functions above.

This solution doesn't consider about performance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.{5}` (any character for the next 5 characters) instead of `.{5,}` (any character for the next 5 or more characters)

The following worked for me using [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) `\w*.{5}$` (improved by @nhahtdh).
This will get all words that are followed by 5 characters.

Results:

```
String "AAAA BBBB CCCC DDEEE"
Match: "DDEEE"

String "AAAA BBBB CCCC DD"
Match: "CCCC DD"

String "AAAA BBBB CCCC"
Match: "BBBB CCCC"

String "AAAA"
Match: null
```

Comment: The solution of `(\w*).{0,5}$` is not entirely correct, since it will matches `"sdfs"`, while the sequence has less than N character. I have not tested all cases, but please check whether `\w*.{5}$` works or not.

Comment: You're right. I did not test with less than 5 characters. The post has been edited, thanks :)